# mod_rewrite to serve subdirectory of docroot as subdomain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to use mod_rewrite to redirect requests to `123.example.com/456/file.html` to `example.com/123/456/file.html`.  The rewrite is necessary because new directories may be created on the fly.  I've tried to reason through it but can't seem to come to a working solution.

First, if I use the below rewrite rules I get a 404 for **everything** because it runs the second rule successfully, does internal redirection, proceeds to run the rules again and the first rule matches because it's looking for `123/123/456/file.html`, causing a 404.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\d+)\.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 !-f
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\d+)\.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/$1 [L]
```

If I move the 404 to be last, I get the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\d+)\.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```

It *almost* works as I need it, but doesn't 404 when you enter `123.example.com/123/`, even though it should be invalid.  Since the path wasn't rewritten by the first rule, `$1` evaluates to `123/` instead of the invalid path `123/123/`, which makes the request succeed without any rewrite rules running.

I feel like I'm very close to getting this to work.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following RewriteCond before your first set of Rules as below to prevent internal redirection

```
#prevent internal redirects
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\d+)\.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 !-f
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much.  That did the trick.  I'll accept your answer as soon as SO allows me to.